# How can I list all videos of an YouTube channel including each video's view count

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using this link

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&part=snippet&channelId=[id]&maxResults=200&key=[key]`

to get all videos from my channel.
And I want to get every videos with view count. When I using `part=statistics` it returns an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, want you want to achieve is not possible: the [`Search.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) API endpoint does not return a video's [`viewCount`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#statistics.viewCount) property.

This behavior is in accordance with the official specs: the [response](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#response) of `Search.list` has its `items` property made of [search resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search#resource) objects. These objects does not provide much details about the respective API resources -- videos, channels or playlists.

When you obtain, upon a `Search.list` invocation, a list of video IDs, you may well ask the [`Videos.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) API endpoint to provide any metadata pertaining to those videos -- including the `viewCount` property.

Do note that the `Videos.list` endpoint accepts its request parameter [`id`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#id) to be a comma-separated list of at most 50 video IDs. Also note that (irrespective of the number of actual IDs passed on to `id`) the [quota cost](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost) of one call to `Videos.list` is *1 unit* (very cheap).

Comment: Thank you for solve my problem. in the beginning I will get all video is by my link above and then I well get all video views by video list